# Customize Context Menu of a library with JavaScript (Script Editor Web Part)

Tags: javascript, script

I'm searching for a way to customize the context menu, which is opened when one clicks on the (...) of any item in any document library.

Following things I would like to realize:

1. I would like to remove the first step of this context menu (the view
   of document) and jump right into the context menu, which is opened
   when one clicks in this "pre-view of the document" again on the
   three points.
2. I would like to have my own entries in this context menu and remove
   all I don't need

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I don't have any access to SharePoint Designer and no rights to edit masterpage - That's why I am kinda dependant on JavaScript solutions for Script Editor Web Part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add new item in context menu within document library than please follow steps mentioned in below links.

[How to Create Context Menus on Pages Document Library in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Create-Context-Menus-on-Pages-Document-Library-in-SharePoint-2013)

If you want to remove the context menu displayed on the first step when you click on (...) than please use below mentioned code.

```
SPList list = site.RootWeb.Lists["YourListName"];
SPField field = list.Fields["Name"];
field.CalloutMenu = false;
field.CalloutMenuAllowed = SPField.ListItemMenuState.Prohibited;
field.ListItemMenu = true;
field.ListItemMenuAllowed = SPField.ListItemMenuState.Required;
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

Comment: The problem is, that I don't have the required VB software on my companies laptop. My only way to embed code is the Script Editor Web Part. I'm also a kinda rookie if its about C#, means I have no clue how to embed C# to SharePoint. Thanks for your help mate :)

Comment: have you tried this if it works for you?...http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2009/02/19/add-custom-context-menu-by-javascript-in-sharepoint/

Comment: it works on SP2007.. Not sure about SP2013

Comment: have you find any solution?

Comment: your comment, showing the tutorial, works to a certain extent. By that I mean it is a way to solve a part of my question, but not completely. It is a solution for my task "2)", but task "1)" seems not to be doable with that or I just don't know the required coding.

Comment: I will check & let you updated

Comment: thank you very much. Btw, do you have any idea how I can make a link out of the button, inserted in the tutorial? I mean the tutorial describes how to insert a button which forces any alert message. But I would need a link to a specific site. 
I've tried it with: 
var strAction = strDisplayText.link("Insert my Site Link here");